# Why does DI return the same DbContext for two different scopes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to add a test to an ASP.NET Core project where an object is created in one scope and then read in another scope. This is to simulate a user creating an object in one POST request and then reading it in another GET Request. However, I'm having trouble properly simulating this scenario.

I have this in my test code

```
SomeDbContext firstContext;
bool isSame;
using (var scope = someServiceProvider.CreateScope()) {
   firstContext = someServiceProvider.GetService<SomeDbContext>();
}

using (var scope = someServiceProvider.CreateScope()) {
   var secondContext = someServiceProvider.GetService<SomeDbContext>();
   isSame = firstContext == secondContext; //should be false, right?
}
```

I expect `isSame` to have a value of `false` when the code above executes but it's actually `true`. Why is that? `SomeDbContext` has a lifetime of scoped when registering it with `AddDbContext()` so it should be destroyed when its scope is disposed and recreated in the second scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your test is incorrect. Although you are creating two separate scopes, you're not actually using them. Here's a working version:

```
SomeDbContext firstContext;
bool isSame;
using (var scope = someServiceProvider.CreateScope()) {
   firstContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SomeDbContext>();
}

using (var scope = someServiceProvider.CreateScope()) {
   var secondContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SomeDbContext>();
   isSame = firstContext == secondContext; //should be false, right?
}
```

Note how `scope.ServiceProvider` is used instead of `someServiceProvider` when resolving dependencies.

The closest thing I can find in the docs is [Call services from main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#call-services-from-main). Although the example shows the `Main` method, it does also demonstrate how the `IServiceProvider` that gets used comes from the scope itself.